# Hibernate inserting to child table a value that is auto-generated sequence in parent table

Tags: java, hibernate

Imagine there is a Work table in Oracle database, the primary key of which is auto-generated sequence. There is another table called External_Reference. They are of One-to-Many relationship, i.e., one work may have many external references.

External_Reference has a foreign key Work_ID to table Work's primary key ID.

With Hibernate, wonder if possible to use [saveOrUpdate(object)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#saveOrUpdate(java.lang.Object)) to save a work `saveOrUpdate(aWork)`, which will automatically save all of its external references?

```
Work work = new Work("Get started with Hibernate");

Set<ExternalReference> externalRefs = new HashSet<>();
ExternalReference ref1 = new ExternalReference("isbn", "23423454");
ref1.setWork(work); // work.getId() returns null before work being saved.
externalRefs.add(ref1);

ExternalReference ref2 = new ExternalReference("doi", "d2342-345553");
ref2.setWork(work);
externalRefs.add(ref2);

work.setExternalReferences(externalRefs);

// ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("External_Reference"."WORK_ID")
aHibernateSession.saveOrUpdate(work);
```

The challenge is, before saving the work, you won't be able to know the auto-generated work ID, which means you cannot assign it to the work's external references.

Yes you can save the work without any external references first to get the auto-generated work ID, and then assign the work ID to all of its external references and save them. But I prefer not to do a two-steps thing to save a single work, if possible.

[image]

Model classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Work")
public class Work implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "WORK_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "WORK_SEQ", sequenceName = "WORK_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)  
    public BigDecimal getId() {
        return this.Id;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "work", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    public Set<ExternalReference> getExternalReferences() {
        return this.externalReferences;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "External_Reference")
public class ExternalReference implements java.io.Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "WORK_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Work getWork() {
        return this.work;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please don't ask us to do your homework. At least show your code, what you've tried, what doesn't work, and where it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to pass just

```
ref1.setWorkId(work);

ref2.setWorkId(work);
```

also, check the hibernate mapping check mapping example

```
//Work Class is Parent
@Entity
@Table(name = "Work")
public class Work {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "TITTLE", nullable = false)
    private String title;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "work")
    private Set<ExternalReference> externalReference;
    public Work() {
    }
    public Work(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    //setter and getter
}
//ExternalReference  Class is Child
@Entity
@Table(name = "External_Reference")
public class ExternalReference {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "Ref_Source", nullable = false)
    private String ref_source;
    @Column(name = "Ref_Id", nullable = false)
    private String ref_id;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name ="Work_ID")
    private Work work;
    public ExternalReference() {
    }
    public ExternalReference(String ref_source, String ref_id) {
        this.ref_source = ref_source;
        this.ref_id = ref_id;
    }
    //setter and getter
}
```

Comment: if have any please let me know

Comment: Thanks @faizakram, I still got the exception, ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("External_Reference"."WORK_ID")

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I thought of and tested is a manual way (for your reference):

- For a new work, manually get the next sequence from the database first, and assign it to the work and all of its external references. Then you can persist the work with all of its external references by just using `aHibernateSession.saveOrUpdate(work);`
- For an existing work, just use its existing ID, and assign it to its new external references if any.

Getting sequences from the database will guarantee that the sequence is unique. It is thread safe.

```
public BigDecimal getNextSeq() {
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession(); // sessionFactory should have been initialised.
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select WORK_SEQ.nextval as num from dual")
                             .addScalar("num", StandardBasicTypes.BIG_DECIMAL);

        BigDecimal nextSeq = (BigDecimal) query.uniqueResult();
        return nextSeq;
    } finally {
        if (session != null){
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

For this workaround to work, you need to comment out the Work's key generator, as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Work")
public class Work implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
    // @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "WORK_SEQ")
    // @SequenceGenerator(name = "WORK_SEQ", sequenceName = "WORK_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)  
    public BigDecimal getId() {
        return this.Id;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "work", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    public Set<ExternalReference> getExternalReferences() {
        return this.externalReferences;
    }

}
```

This workaround is a manual way, not elegant, but works. Still hoping to find the elegant approach, it must exist somewhere, as this is a quite common use case.